# 特定の複数のカテゴリーに属する記事を、チェックボックス選択で一覧表示したい

Tags: wordpress

チェックボックスによる選択で、このようなURLを得たいと思っています

```
my domain/category/slugA+slugB
```

現状、下記のコードを用意しているのですが、得られているURLはこのようなものです（%2bは+を表しています）

```
my domain/?category=SlugA%2bSlugB
```

用意したコード

```html
<form class="cat-search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
  <input type="checkbox" value="SlugA" id="cat0" class="cats2" /><label for="cat0">Category1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="SlugB" id="cat1" class="cats2" /><label for="cat1">Category2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="SlugC" id="cat2" class="cats2" /><label for="cat2">Category3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="SlugD" id="cat3" class="cats2" /><label for="cat3">Category4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="SlugE" id="cat4" class="cats2" /><label for="cat4">Category5</label>
  <input type="hidden" id="cat2" name="category" />
  <input type="submit" class="cat-search" value="search" />
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.cats2', function() {
    var cats = $('.cats2:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join("+");
    $('#cat2').val(cats);
  });
});
```

そもそも、チェックボックスを使って、求めているURLが取得できるのか、わかりません。

疑問符は必ず入ってしまうし、そもそも求めているURLの形式にはできないのであらば、あきらめもつくのですが、どなたかおわかりになる方いましたら、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/240273

Comment: 編集していただいた方、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決いたしました。
検索プラグインを使って、意図していた表示ができるようになりました。
編集していただいた方、ありがとうございました。

使用したプラグインはSearch and Filterの有料版です。

Comment: 差し支えなければ具体的なプライグイン名を書き添えておいてもらうと、同じような疑問を持った人の助けになると思います。

Comment: こんにちは。具体的なプラグイン情報を追加しました